# How to place components above React Native Modal?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, react-native, floating-action-button

I'm developing an app using React Native. Right now, I have a FAB button which I'm using the [react-native-circular-action-menu](https://github.com/geremih/react-native-circular-action-menu) and I'm using the React Native Modal to open a modal. The problem is the Modal occupies the entire screen and I placed a View inside of the Modal component to adjust the width and size of the modal. I managed the size the modal using the view and setting transparency true for the modal.

However, I couldn't click on the FAB button as the modal's component is actually on top of it. I want to place the FAB button on top of the modal and on top of all components in the app. Is there any way to do it?

Thank you.

[image]